# Check table on refresh, compare add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This might be hard for me to explain, but I will try my best.

I have a table, that is setup similar to:

```
<tr>
  <td class="tac">3</td>
  <td><a href="/horse/speared">Speared</a></td>
  <td class="tac">9</td>
  <td>L Camilleri</td>
  <td class="br tac">58kg</td>
  <td id="odd" class="tac betNumber"><a href="#"></a></td>
  <td id="odd" class="tac betNumber"><a href="#">15</a></td>
  <td id="odd" class="tac betNumber"><a href="#">15</a></td>
  <td id="odd" class="tac betNumber"><a href="#">15</a></td>
  <td id="odd" class="tac betNumber"><a href="#">13</a></td>
  <td id="odd" class="tac betNumber"><a href="#">21</a></td>
  <td id="odd" class="tac betNumber"><a href="#">13</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>4</td>
  <td><a href="/horse/sneakin-around">Sneakin' Around</a></td>
  <td class="tac">17</td>
  <td>P King</td>
  <td class="br tac">58kg</td>
  <td id="odd" class="tac betNumber"><a href="#"></a></td>
  <td id="odd" class="tac betNumber"><a href="#">11</a></td>
  <td id="odd" class="tac betNumber"><a href="#">12</a></td>
  <td id="odd" class="tac betNumber"><a href="#">11</a></td>
  <td id="odd" class="tac betNumber"><a href="#">21</a></td>
  <td id="odd" class="tac betNumber"><a href="#">12</a></td>
  <td id="odd" class="tac betNumber"><a href="#">21</a></td>
</tr>
```

the td with the id="odd" I want to check if they changed, and if they did, add a class "updated" that will only flash or last for 2-3 seconds.  I load the code with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#responsedcontainer").load("/odd-single.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
   $("#responsedcontainer").load("/odd-single.php&randval="+ Math.random());
   }, 3000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

which loads and then refreshes every 3 seconds. so after the refresh happens, check the last refresh and see if any of the td have changed values, if so, add a style for 2-3 seconds.

I am new to javascript/jquery, so please be patient with me.

Thanks

Comment: all your TDs are changing or only one of them ?

Comment: all the td's with the id of odd

Comment: side note: do not use multiple ids with the same name. I see your id='odd' many times. IDs should be unique.

Comment: @andrew i could make them unique if i needed to. they are there only for this example that i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a hidden input to each of your td's with the same value as your "a" tag has, for example:

```
    <td id="odd" class="tac betNumber">
        <a href="#">21</a>
        <input type="hidden" class="changeTriggerer" value="21"/>
    </td>
```

On this input you can define a change event handler:

```
   function clearUpdateClass(){
       setTimeout( function(){
           $('td.updated').removeClass('updated');
       },3000);
   };

   $(document).ready(function() {

       $("td#odd input.changeTriggerer").on('change', function(){
           $(this).parent().addClass('updated');
           clearUpdateClass();
       });

   });
```

I didn't tested it, but hopefully its working, i hope it helped you!

**EDIT**

1. I found out,with jquery load function, the DOM isn't refreshed as expected, and the jquery selectors, doesn't works, so i suggest you, to use the below function for loading the page:

   ```
   function loadPage( url ){}
   ```
2. If your table data, row count, or row order can change, than you should change the td attributes as follows:

   ```
   <td id="uniqeCellId" class="changeable tac betNumber"><a href="#"></a></td>
   ```
3. Add 2 other functions, one for load the values, second for check changes:

   ```
   function saveTableData(){}
   function checkTableData(){}
   ```

**FINALLY**: The whole code:

```
    var beforeLoadData = [];

    function loadPage( url ){
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("GET", url , false);
        ajax.send();
        $("#responsedcontainer").html( ajax.responseText );
    }

    function saveTableData(){
        beforeLoadData = [];
        $("td.changeable").each( function(){
            beforeLoadData.push( { "key": $(this).attr('id'), "value": $(this).text() } );
        }); 
    }

    function getSavedValueFor( key ){
        for( var i in beforeLoadData ){
            if( beforeLoadData[i].key === key )
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    function checkTableData(){
        $("td.changeable").each( function(){
            var thisValue = { "key": $(this).attr('id'), "value": $(this).text() };
            var index = getSavedValueFor( thisValue.key );
            if( index >= 0){
                if( beforeLoadData[index].value !== thisValue.value )
                    $( "td#"+thisValue.key ).addClass( 'updated' );
            }else{
                //new row, if you need then you can add updated class hear too.
            }
        });
    }

    function removeUpdatedClass( ){
        setTimeout( function(){
            $('td.updated').removeClass('updated');
        },3000);
    }

    $(function(){
        //saveTableData();
        loadPage( "/odd-single.php" );
        //checkTableData();
        //removeUpdatedClass();
        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            saveTableData();
            loadPage("/odd-single.php&randval="+ Math.random());
            checkTableData();
            removeUpdatedClass();
        }, 3000);
    });
```

Comment: I added this, verified input's were correct, and didn't do anything. unfortunately i don't think this will work, as the current code i have is just basically "refreshing" the div.

Comment: Ohh, so your whole table is reloaded, not just the values in td? Than the only solution is, if you save each td value in a structure before load, and you will check changes after load... Probably you should reconsider the reloading technique.

Comment: Yes, exactly, and Or Duan wrote a nice answer. I only suggest you to call the removeClass delay after the each() function, and call it once, not for each element. this solution works nice, if the row number, and its order doesn't change.

Comment: I tried this new code in replace of mine, and the load function didn't even load the page /odds-single.php ?

Comment: And, if you try this one: $("#responsedcontainer").load("/odd-single.php"); Insteed of my load function?

Comment: ok you can see this video: http://screencast.com/t/566fwI7Q just a big block is being changed.  nothing in the table is being changed, so shouldn't do that. the green boxes are the "updated" css class. i feel we're close, i just need one more push :D

Comment: <td id="uniqeCellId", the uniqeCellId, should be unique for each entry, so in php, this should be an iterator, witch doesn't duplicate. For example: cell1, cell2, cell3, ... Please, check to be different for each cell!

Comment: Please, recheck to be sure! This code should work fine, if you have unique keys! If you want to be sure, in the id, add a row number value too, for example: <td id = "odd1_11", the first number to be the row number, the second one the cell number.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so came up with this idea:

First get an array with all the current text(before the changing):

```
$("td#odd").each(function(){
    beforChange.push($(this).text());
});
```

after that that we will scan the array and compare to the current value:

```
var i=0;
$("td#odd").each(function(){
    if($(this).text() != beforChange[i]){
         $(this).addClass('updated');
        alert("After:" + $(this).text() + ". Befor:" + beforChange[i]);
         setTimeout( function(){
              $('td.updated').removeClass('updated');

         },2000);
    }
    i++;
});
```

**EDIT:**

I made a jsfiddle for you, i forgot to put i++, so now its working:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/efsej/1/)

let me know if that helped.

goodluck.

Comment: Tried this.  Seems like it's close.  Maybe im wrong, it's not working, but I tried adding: `alert(beforChange[0]);` or `console.log(beforChange)` and is empty.  Would that be correct?

Comment: I added td#odd, and now am getting an array of numbers. and I added this in both locations, but unfortunately still not working. I will keep messing around until i hear back from you.

Comment: based on @Or Duan code, try changing your id='odd' to class='odd' and the code from $("#odd").each(function(){
to $("td.odd").each(function(){
perhaps the same ids causing it to misbehave?

Comment: I will try that now.  However I have it working, but it's changing all td with id = odd to the class when 1 updates.

Comment: @user2639176 i updated the code and and put a jsfiddle for you. its working now.

Comment: hmm, thought it would work. I changed your alert to console.log, and nothing even logs or alerts. I see in the jsfiddle. I hate to keep bothering you, so i guess let me play around and see what i can figure out.

Comment: maybe because some td's are blank.  when i `console.log($(this).text());` before the if statement, i do see the results (not in an array like the before) but i see the numbers, and then sporatically, i see (an empty string) in the console log, where the td is blank.

Comment: ok, looking through the console log, it must be the way i am refreshing the div. I am making a manual change in the db, so i know the very first td will change. once it does, i am outputting before and after, and they are both the same (after). i hope that makes sense.  So it must be something with my div .load

Comment: keep trying i feel your really close, if you print one of the .text() and its empty its because there is noting in the td. that why i changed the td's text to numbers(indexs). you can see that i did change the table, and its works, if you need help with the change of the table. post the code and let me know.